# Why is my array of structures not working?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, structure

[How to do question 2?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fhh2.png)

1. Write a program that defines a struct student to hold the following information for a student:
   surname, other names, address, age. The program should have the following functions:
    A function inputStudent() that takes a student struct as parameter and allows of input of
   data that are stored in the struct parameter.
    A function displayStudent() that takes a student struct as parameter and displays the
   attribute values on the screen.
   The program should declare two variables of type student, allow input of data for two students and
   store them in those variables. The program should then display the names and address of the older
   student among the two. If they are of the same age, the program should display the names and
   addresses of both of them.
2. Modify the program in question 2, so that the main() function declares an array of size 20 of the
   struct student, allows the input of an integer value n, and performs the input of data for n students,
   then displays them back. The program should then display the name, address and age of the
   youngest student in the array. If there are several students with the youngest age, the program will
   display only the first one.

---

I am having problems with Question2.. I created an array of structures but I have errors and I dont know how to correct them.
what mistake have I made? Please, help. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct student{
    char surname[50];
    char otherNames[70];
    char addr[50];
    int age;

};
struct student inputStudent(struct student *s){

    printf("Enter surname: ");
    fgets(s->surname,50,stdin);

    printf("Enter other names: ");
    fgets(s->otherNames,70,stdin);

    printf("Enter address: ");
    fgets(s->addr,50,stdin);

    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d",&s->age);
    getchar();
    printf("\n");

}

void displayStudent(struct student *s){
    printf("Surname: %s" ,s->surname);
    printf("Other names: %s", s->otherNames);
    printf("Address: %s ",s->addr);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
   
    struct student c[20];
    int n;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        intputStudent(&c);
    }
    int youngest =100;

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        if(c[i].age < youngest){
            displayStudent(&c[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i < 20` should be `i < n` -- isn't that the reason you asked for `n`?

Comment: You can't know if a student is youngest until you get to the end of the loop. You're displaying every student younger than 100, not the youngest.

Comment: Okay, so you "have errors". Did you try to read them? Did you try to figure out what part of the code they are referring to? Did you try putting the text of those error messages into a search engine? Did you try to look for other questions on Stack Overflow about those error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You should only input `n` students, not `20`. You need to pass the address of just the current student in the array to `inputStudent()`, not the address of the whole array.

Then after you input them all, you need to find the index of the student with the youngest age. You're printing every student younger than 100.

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        intputStudent(&c[i]);
    }
    int youngest = c[0].age;
    int youngest_index = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(c[i].age < youngest){
            youngest = c[i].age;
            youngest_index = i;
        }
    }
    displayStudent(c[youngest_index]);
```